# iOS unable to remove Notification observer. Deinit not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, nsnotification, deinit

I have a UIView similar to the one you can see below:

```
class ViewTaskViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    subscribeToNotifications()
}

func subscribeToNotifications() {
    let notification = NotificationCenter.default
    notification.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: "TimerUpdated"), object: nil, queue: nil, using: handleUpdateTimer)
    print("Subscribed to NotificationCenter in ViewTaskViewController")
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    print("TUFU TUFU TUFU")
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

deinit {
    print("DENINT")
}

@objc func handleUpdateTimer(notification: Notification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo, let timeInSeconds = userInfo["timeInSeconds"] as? Int {

        withUnsafePointer(to: &self.view) {
            print("We got timeeeeee \(timeInSeconds) \($0)")
        }

       //do something here....
    }
}
```

}

The issue I am having is that I am unable to remove the observers from this particular UIView when the user hits the back button and returns to another viewController.

`ViewWillDisppear` is called but `deinit` is not called. The strange thing is that if we remove `subscribeToNotifications()` from `viewDidLoad()` then the `deinit` is called.

The other issue is related to a memory leak. As you can see in the screenshot below, when the view does subscribe to notifications and the user leaves/re-enters the view, the memory usage increase. [image]

Now compare that to when the `subscribeToNotifications()` is commented out, there is no increase in memory usage and only one instance of the viewController. 
[image]
The conclusion is that there seems to be a correlation between the notification subscription creation of a new instance of the UIView hence the `deinit` is not being called.

I'd like to find out if there is a way we can deinitialize the view and unsubscribe from the notification.

Please let me know if you need further information. :)

Comment: Documentation for the `addObserver` method you're using says, "To unregister observations, you pass the **object returned by this method** to removeObserver(_:)."  Instead, you seem to be assuming that `self` is the registered object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the removeObserver() only works if you use this version of addObserver()

```
notification.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.handleUpdateTimer), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "TimerUpdated"), object: nil)
```

I'm guessing with the original version you aren't actually indicating who the observer is.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I had already tried what Khalid had suggested but still wasn't getting it remove the observer. But your method certainly helps and solves the issue! :)

Answer (score 2):

As @Spads said you can use

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(subscribeToNotifications), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TimerUpdate"), object: nil)
```

or the one you already have. 
you can remove your notification by it's name or it's reference

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: "TimerUpdate", object: nil)
```

if you declared your notification at the top of your class then you can directly pass the reference of your notification to be removed in your case **notification**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(notification)
```

Comment: So I did try that even before submitting this question and didn't get it to work, although the other method of adding observer seems to have done the trick! :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should store your newly added observer in a opaque object (`NSObjectProtocol`) and then call `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self.nameOfObserver)`